# Authentication Problem: Even after typing the correct passoword

Tags: wi-fi

I have Digisol router in my home. My phone was connected to it for a time, but then suddenly it started showing **no internet**. So I tried to reconnect by **Forgot** password. But since then I am facing the *Authentication Problem** every time I tried to connect.
Some points:

- It is connected to a PC by LAN and two phones by WiFi. It is working fine in all of them.
- I have tried to *clear Google Services Framework* cache and restart. Still nothing happened.
- Also I tried to turn Airplane mode on and off.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

That's a common problem that occurs with may users.
well the solution is pretty simple 
Go to settings > wifi > select the wifi you want to connet
Now when it ask for password.
Fill the password.
down below there will be advance settings open that. Locate Ip settings and change it from DHCP  to Static 
there just change de ip to 192.168.1.X
[X] be any number like 32,24,64 [image: Click here to see my configuration.]

just do that and click connect. it will connect.